# Prepopulate value in lookup field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to prepopulate lookup field but unable to do.

Below is the code I have followed.

http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/

In init method, i kept like -  `component.set("v.selectedLookUpRecord",response.getReturnValue().Id);`

In component like:

```
<c:customLookup objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" recordName="{!v.oppRec.Account__c}" recordId="{!v.oppRec.Account__c}" selectedRecord="{!v.oppRec.Account__c}"   />

        </div> 
        123 {!v.oppRec.Account__c}
```

I am able to display value on UI after 123 but unable to display name inside lookup field. Please let me know how to populate.

Answer (score 0):

I had also gone through the same issue, then I build an aura method into the custom lookup component and a function in component's controller.js file.
Below is the code.

Aura Method in **component**.

```
<aura:method name="updateSelected" action="{!c.updateLookup}"/>
```

**Controller.js**

```
updateLookup : function(cmp, event, helper){
    var recordId = cmp.get('v.selectedId');
    var recordName = cmp.get('v.selectedName');
    if(!recordId){//if current record is null then clear it
        helper.clearCurrentSelection(cmp); //Clear all the value
    }else if(recordId && !recordName){
        //if we have the Id then call the helper method
        helper.searchHelper(cmp, selectedId);
    }
}
```

After creating this method, just create an aura method in the customLookup component and call this aura method whenever you want to update the lookup.

Comment: Can you please share aura method of component. so that it will help me

Comment: I have updated the answer